# How do I convert a dataset into time series data in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame that I am attempting to turn into a time series. The following is an image of a few rows of data. As you can see, **the data frame does not include every single day**. So, is there a way to change this into time series data? Because the code I have here does not account for the missing days.

```
df3 <- ts(df2$Freq, start=c(2015), end=c(2017), frequency=365)
```

[image]

```
structure(list(Police_Killings = structure(c(16437, 16438, 16439, 
16440, 16441, 16442), class = "Date"), Freq = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It is already time series data because it is collected sequentially over time. Do you mean you want a ts object? Or do you want any kind of R object that respects the time series nature of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data which you have is a dataframe, you can use `complete` from `tidyr` to fill in the missing dates and fill their `Freq` column with 0.

```
tidyr::complete(df, Police_Killings = seq(min(Police_Killings), 
      max(Police_Killings), by = "1 day"), fill = list(Freq = 0))
```

You can then convert this to a time-series object as needed for further processing.

Comment: I am getting this error message: Error in Summary.factor(1:879, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @CynicalF The `dput` you have shared has the class "Date" for `Police_Killings` column but data which you are using has class "factor". Do `df$Police_Killings <- as.Date(df$Police_Killings, "%Y/%m/%d)` and then run the above again.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry about the confusion, I had created too many data frames and was looking at the incorrect one.

Answer (score 1):

`ts` is normally not used for daily series.  It is mostly used for regularly spaced monthly and quarterly series.  You can represent this as a zoo or xts series.

```
library(zoo)

d <- data.frame(date = "2017/01/01", Freq = 3)  # sample data
z <- read.zoo(d, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am really looking to make it into time series data.

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate()` package is great for converting into date formats.

```
library(lubridate)

df3$Police_Killings <- ymd(df3$Police_Killings)
```

Comment: Using the str() function, it shows that this is in fact a data frame and not a time series.

Comment: please update your question with a reproducible example, using `dput()` to provide some sample data from R. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My dataset is far too large to include this, which is why I added the image of the two columns my data frame has.

Comment: do `dput(head(df))` after selecting the 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution for converting data frame to a (daily) time-series (ts) object:

```
df$year_of_police_killings <- as.numeric(format(df$Police_Killings, "%Y"))

date_range <- range(df$Police_Killings)

year_range <- range(df$year_of_police_killings)

min_step_in_min_year <- min(as.numeric(strftime(df$Police_Killings[as.numeric(format(df$Police_Killings, "%Y")) == min(year_range)], "%j")))

max_step_in_max_year <- max(as.numeric(strftime(df$Police_Killings[as.numeric(format(df$Police_Killings, "%Y")) == max(year_range)], "%j")))

dat_ts <- ts(df$Freq, start = c(min(year_range), min_step_in_min_year),

            end = c(max(year_range), max_step_in_max_year), frequency = 365)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the `tsibble` package to represent it as a time series:

```
library(tsibble)
ts_killings <- as_tsibble(df, index = Police_Killings)
```

You may fill gaps with

```
ts_killings %>% 
    fill_gaps(Freq = 0)
```

A nice introduction in working with `tsibble` can be found in the vignette: [Introduction to tsibble](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tsibble/vignettes/intro-tsibble.html)